# How to apply coupon code on Custom tab in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, discount, coupon, tabs

I have created Custom Tabs in Magento 2 Between Shipping and Review and Payment.

I want to remove Discount Coupon Code from Review and Payment to my Custom Tabs.How will i do it ?

I think this part is used to show coupan in checkout_index_index.xml

```
<item name="summary" xsi:type="array">
<item name="children" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_SalesRule/js/view/payment/discount</item>
        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="errors" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_SalesRule/js/view/payment/discount-messages</item>
                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">messages</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </item>
</item>
```

But doesn't show up the fields.

Comment: do you mean you want to remove default place of coupen code block?

Comment: Yes I want remove default coupon block and add it to my Custom Tab.@DhirenVasoya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove Coupon Code block create the following file.

> Vendor\Extension\view\frontend\layout\checkout_index_index.xml

Add this code into that file.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="afterMethods" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="discount" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Main logic is into this line, which remove that block.

```
<item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
```

Comment: Yes it has removed the discount coupan from checkout page Thanks for that but how would i add that coupan in my custom tab @Dhiren

Comment: that depend on, how you added tab there. If above answer help you up-vote and accept  as solution, so it will help other in community.

Comment: I have created checkout_index_index.xml in my custom module and created checkout js file and after that in template folder created html files for the same. 
If you need further code i have attached it @Dhiren

Comment: Have you check the default block code? you can take reference of that one.

Comment: Which default block code i didn't understand it will you please explain this @Dhiren

Comment: How they added default coupen codes.

Comment: No not yet checked okk will do then update you if face any problem @Dhiren

Comment: Ok try and let me know.

Comment: I have updated my question which i have added in checkout_index_index.xml but it doesn't show up the fields. will you please help.@Dhiren

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111168/discussion-between-dhiren-vasoya-and-prits).

Comment: @Prits ask the seprate questoin for this one, so other also can give you answer.

Comment: already asked in https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/318523/how-to-add-discount-coupon-code-on-custom-tab-in-magento-2 please have a look if any idea @Dhiren