# How to add discount coupon code on Custom tab in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, discount, coupon, tabs

I have created Custom Tabs in Magento 2 Between Shipping and Review and Payment.

I want to remove Discount Coupon Code from Review and Payment to my Custom Tabs.How will i do it ?

[image]

I have already removed discount coupan from Review and Payment Screen. Now, i want to add it in my Custom tab ex. My Step Two Title.

How would i do that ?

I have added here one JS file and one HTML file but for each step i have added 3 js and html file.

Comment: how you added this steps?

Comment: Updated one js and html file with checkout_index_index.xml will you please check.@DhirenVasoya

Comment: is there any thing which you find would be helpfull @DhirenVasoya

Answer (score 0):

if you check the checkout_index_index file there should be a tree almost identical to yours which includes the coupon block. You should be able to replicate it to insert that block as a child as you already done with new steps.

Try to take the path from here: [How can i hide Discount Code form checkout payment page in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/159986/how-can-i-hide-discount-code-form-checkout-payment-page-in-magento-2)

***Update***

Here's how to move the coupon block: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51454608/how-to-move-apply-coupon-to-side-bar-in-magento-2-in-checkout-page

Cheers

Comment: I have updated my checkout_index_index with discount code in in step 3 but it doesn't appear on my step My step two title will you please help @Riccardo

Comment: I updated the comment @Prits

Comment: Yes i have checked it .it move to sidebar i have copy from accepted from summery code in like and added it in checkout_index_index.xml but it doesn't work.@Riccardo