# How to Save data from Checkout new Steps in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, database, save, savedata, payment-step

I want to save data from Checkout new Steps in Magento 2 ?

[image]

I have created two text fields in My Step Two Title Tabs which is successfully created but how to save those value in database after successfully order placed.

Comment: How you added this fields here?

Comment: That i will tell in https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/318523/how-to-add-discount-coupon-code-on-custom-tab-in-magento-2 in this please look into this @DhirenVasoya

Answer (score 0):

if you want to handle the data after order confirmation you can hang on to the sales_order_place_after event through an observer.
Here events list: https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-events.html
Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your response will you please suggest me any link how can i create database column for my custom attribute.@Riccardo

Comment: If you want to create a product custom attribute you should not create a direct column in the database but follow this link: https://devdocs.magento.com/videos/fundamentals/add-new-product-attribute/

Comment: Okk Thanks for the help.
Will You please look into this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/318523/how-to-add-discount-coupon-code-on-custom-tab-in-magento-2 It will really helpful @Riccardo

Comment: @Prits yees of course